# Set a background color for a markdown multiline block or citation. Attempting to do so loses the markdown formatage inside a citation

Tags: pdf, latex, markdown

In a *markdown* document, created to produce a pdf through *Pandoc*, I have this citation:

```
> \underline{Dépenses d'aides sociales obligatoires par les départements, en \textcolor{Orchid}{2016 : 36.8 milliards d'euros}}
>
>   - insertion : 10 milliards d'euros.
>   - personnes âgées : 6.9
>   - handicap : 7
>   - enfance : 6
```

that produces this :

[image]

But if I attempt to surround it by a `tcolorbox`, with:

- a `\begin{tcolorbox}` before the first line
- and an `\end{tcolorbox}` after the last one,

it produces this:

[image]

loosing all the markdown classical formatting.

Over the Internet, examples are showing single line color boxes, and aren't taking into account this problem.

I don't know how to adapt my *markdown* document a way I can set when I want (not all the time) a block or citation to get a background color, but without loosing usual markdown rules of formatage.

---

Here is a sample of *markdown* file that produces a well formatted citation, but without background color (it's a normal markdown):

```markdown
> \underline{Dépenses d'aides sociales obligatoires par les départements, en 2016 : 36.8 milliards d'euros}
>
>   - insertion : 10 milliards d'euros.
>   - personnes âgées : 6.9
>   - handicap : 7
>   - enfance : 6
```

Here, the one doing the issue:

```markdown
---
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tcolorbox}
---

\begin{tcolorbox}
> \underline{Dépenses d'aides sociales obligatoires par les départements, en 2016 : 36.8 milliards d'euros}
>
>   - insertion : 10 milliards d'euros.
>   - personnes âgées : 6.9
>   - handicap : 7
>   - enfance : 6
\end{tcolorbox}
```

---

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Your response solved most of my problem. But there are still two troubles.

**1)** From a document with the verbatim environment below, I added few command creating the boxes I was looking for:

```latex
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{breaklines,breakanywhere,breaksymbol=,breakanywheresymbolpre=,commandchars=\\\{\}}

\newcommand{\cadreAvantage}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=green!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=green!75!black}}
\newcommand{\cadreAttention}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=orange!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=orange!80!black}}
\newcommand{\cadreDanger}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=red!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,colframe=red!75!black}}
\newcommand{\cadreTransparent}{\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=white!5!white,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt,lowerbox=invisible,code={\tcbset{enlarge left by=1cm}}}}
```

If I have a long markdown blockquote that without `tcolorbox` displays that:
(Ile-de-France and after are under >)

[image]

then putting a `\cadreAvantage` above transforms it that way:

[image]

It is crushed. Line spacing are not correctly honored.

**2)** There's no way to return to "normal" markdown blockquote definition. Even trying to use something like `\cadreTransparent` doesn't have really the same effect - and I do it wrongly it still has a border -)

I better have something like

```latex
\cadreAvantage{
>   __Ile-de-France : Internationalisation et Import / Export__
>   
>   - exportations : \donnee{77 milliards d'euros} (2016)
>   - importations : \donnee{129 milliards d'euros} (2016)  
>   - Exportation vers : Europe, Etats-Unis
   ...
}

but I don't know how to write it!
```

Comment: Can you either make a [mre] or show the intermediate .tex file from your first code block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pandoc translates the quote into a latex `quote` environment. You could redefine it to be a tcolorbox:

```
---
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    - \renewtcolorbox{quote}{}
---

> \underline{Dépenses d'aides sociales obligatoires par les départements, en 2016 : 36.8 milliards d'euros}
>
>   - insertion : 10 milliards d'euros.
>   - personnes âgées : 6.9
>   - handicap : 7
>   - enfance : 6
```

[image]

(the first line overflows because `\underline` can't break lines, if you want line breaks, have a look at the soul or lua-ul packages)

---

You can use the same idea to create quotes of different colours:

```
---
header-includes:
    - \colorlet{mycolor}{red}
    - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    - \renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=mycolor}
---

> \underline{Dépenses d'aides sociales obligatoires par les départements, en 2016 : 36.8 milliards d'euros}
>
>   - insertion : 10 milliards d'euros.
>   - personnes âgées : 6.9
>   - handicap : 7
>   - enfance : 6

\colorlet{mycolor}{white}
> test

\colorlet{mycolor}{cyan}
> test
```

[image]

---

Or if you just want to change a single block:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{tcolorbox}
---

> \underline{Dépenses d'aides sociales obligatoires par les départements, en 2016 : 36.8 milliards d'euros}
>
>   - insertion : 10 milliards d'euros.
>   - personnes âgées : 6.9
>   - handicap : 7
>   - enfance : 6

> test

\begingroup
\renewtcolorbox{quote}{colback=red}
> test


\endgroup

> test
```

[image]

Comment: It works, but it changes __all__ the citations to a gray background color. It's not what I am looking for. Most of mine shall stay as they are, some have a green background, some an orange one, etc.

Comment: @MarcLeBihan You can change the colour between quotes